# magento 2 errors : General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Tags: magento2, database

I am getting below error every second or third day.

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\LockWaitException):
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try
>   restarting transaction, query was: INSERT INTO `customer_visitor`
>   (`customer_id`, `session_id`, `last_visit_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
>   Exception #1 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
>   error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction,
>   query was: INSERT INTO `customer_visitor` (`customer_id`,
>   `session_id`, `last_visit_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?) Exception #2
>   (PDOException): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout
>   exceeded; try restarting transaction

I see **table customer_visitor** have above **22000 records**. Can we clear this table?

I also check in my staging site for same table having 12 records and it never increase records of customer visitor.

How can I cleaning up **customer_visitor table log**. is it creates any problems if cleaning up this table

Answer (score 8):

I also faced the same issue and found the solution.

First, enter in Mysql using terminal/cli with below commands

```
mysql -u [db username]_user -p
use [db username]_db
```

View running processes by following command

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

[image]

Then kill the process in 'command' sleep
in my case the process in the first row with id 22023836

```
KILL 2202836;
```

Then refresh the page and the issue is solved now.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to clear the tables on schedule?

If so you need an extension. check this:

https://github.com/rakeshmagento/magento2-db-log-cleaner

This will truncate the tables in readme though so check that's what you want.