# Magento to upgrade to 2.3.3 issue

Tags: upgrade

I have upgraded the Magento version to 2.3.3 successfully, but when I try to run the command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

I am getting this error:

`error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction, query was: ALTER TABLE sales_order_grid MODIFY COLUMN base_grand_total decimal(20, 4)  NULL  COMMENT "Base Grand Total", MODIFY COLUMN base_total_paid decimal(20, 4)  NULL  COMMENT "Base Total Paid", MODIFY COLUMN grand_total decimal(20, 4)  NULL  COMMENT "Grand Total", MODIFY COLUMN total_paid decimal(20, 4)  NULL  COMMENT "Total Paid", MODIFY COLUMN subtotal decimal(20, 4)  NULL  COMMENT "Subtotal", MODIFY COLUMN shipping_and_handling decimal(20, 4)  NULL  COMMENT "Shipping and handling amount", MODIFY COLUMN total_refunded decimal(20, 4)  NULL  COMMENT "Total Refunded"`

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220790/magento-2-errors-general-error-1205-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restartin?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: Unfortunately It won't worked for me :( .

Comment: did you try sudo php -dmemory_limit =-1 bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: is your mysql cofig default or custom?

Comment: So finally I got the solution.

I just increase the memory limit with 4 GB and run command with memory limit:
 php -dmemory_limit=4G bin/magento setup:upgrade