# Magento 2.3.3 customer password update after customer login not working

Tags: customer, magento2.3.3, password, customer-login

I have customer password change using this [way](https://magecomp.com/blog/change-customer-password-programmatically-in-magento-2/) and password change successfully 
after i am login customer then login is not working below type error showing and before password change also not login this customer

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction, query was: UPDATE `customer_entity` SET `failures_num` = ?, `first_failure` = ?, `lock_expires` = ? WHERE (entity_id = '20377')

customer login 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction,
```

After i have also truncate `customer_visitor` table and restart *mysql server* but still no luck for me

then i am login customer and it's going **504 Gateway Timeout**

[image]

Comment: Have you checked this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/273649/59677 ?

Comment: @KishorThummar yes i see but no any kill process still database as normal

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the innodb lock wait timeout setting in php.ini file.

```
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=5000
```

If not working also try to ensure the nginx and php-fpm did not timeout.

```
fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
proxy_read_timeout 600;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but same customer working on devsite and production website not working